# Combining three images into a pie chart

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wish to combine three circles into a cirlce graph in xaml for windows phone (8). Basically I got these three images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I want to combine them, so I can create a circle graph from them, if that makes any sense.

If possible, it would be cool to be able to create it into a control, so I just had to add it to the page and then apply the values that will tell how much each "circle" should be shown.

```
<Image Source="/Images/157385.png" Height="200" Margin="0,0,279,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="200" >
     <Image.Clip>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="250" RadiusY="250"/>
     </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

but it ends up looking more like this:
[image]

```
<Image Source="/Images/157385.png" Height="200" Margin="0,0,279,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="200" >
     <Image.Clip>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="250" RadiusY="250"/>
     </Image.Clip>
</Image>
<Image Source="/Images/157387.png" Height="200" Margin="1,0,279,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="200" >
     <Image.Clip>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="100"/>
     </Image.Clip>
</Image>
<Image Source="/Images/157388.png" Height="200" Margin="1,0,279,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="200" >
     <Image.Clip>
          <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="50"/>
     </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Is there any good approach to this? ^_^ or any suggestions, everything is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipping an element is about overlapping (see [How to Crop an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189065%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). So in your sample, you have an ellipse with an ellipse overlapping it. You cannot create a pie wedge with two ellipses. Here is a sample of how to create a pie wedge. This sample uses an Ellipse to mimic your image.

```
<Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Clip>
        <PathGeometry >
            <PathFigureCollection>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50,50">
                    <LineSegment Point="0,0"></LineSegment>
                    <LineSegment Point="50,0"></LineSegment>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathFigureCollection>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Ellipse.Clip>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Well, this is definately starting to look better. I'm having a hard time, getting it to work fully, but I just need to play around with it. Thanks though, I'll accept this as the solution to my problem :)

Comment: Clipping takes some practice. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good starting point for anything working on images is to check out WriteableBitmapEx!
The lib is available for winphone.

[Link here...](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) ( with examples on the bottom, but when you google you'll find more )